# ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty): rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I get the error `ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):` when I click on the sign up link. I created a form partial which I then render on the new.html.erb file. The error appears to be from the users controller. Here is the code.

```
class UsersController <  Clearance::UsersController
  def new
    @user = User.new 
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @shouts = @user.shouts
  end

  private

   def new
     @user = User.new
     render template: "users/new"
   end

   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
   end
end
```

users/new.html.erb

```
<div id="clearance" class="sign-up">
  <h2><%= t(".title") %></h2>

  <%= form_for @user do |form| %>
    <%= render partial: '/users/form', object: form %>

    <div class="submit-field">
      <%= form.submit %>
    </div>

    <div class="other-links">
      <%= link_to t(".sign_in"), sign_in_path %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="text-field">
  <%= form.label :email %>
  <%= form.email_field :email%>
</div>

<div class="text-field">
  <%= form.label :username %>
  <%= form.text_field :username%>
</div>

<div class="password-field">
  <%= form.label :password %>
  <%= form.password_field :password %>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have your `new` method as private?

Comment: @jdgray this was the issue all along ! thank you. I had to remove the new action below the private call.